# Double pagination in one view for CI 3

Tags: php, pagination, codeigniter-3

We need to have two different pagination tables for one view because a client wanted to have it. It shows up no problem, but the problem is, when I change the pages of the first table, it's fine. But when I change the second table to the second of this page, the highlight of the second page don't light up.

Any advice? Or any possible alternate solutions for having two paginations in one view?

my config is:

```
$data['title'] = 'Dashboard ';
    $configPendingDash = array();
    $configOpenDash = array();

    $configPendingDash["base_url"] = base_url() . "/index.php/Users/dashboard";
    $configPendingDash["total_rows"] = $this->Users_model->get_count_pending_applications();
    $configPendingDash["per_page"] = 5;
    $configPendingDash["uri_segment"] = 3;

    $configOpenDash["base_url"] = base_url() . "/index.php/Users/dashboard/".$this->uri->segment(3,0);
    $configOpenDash["total_rows"] = $this->Users_model->get_count_open_applications();
    $configOpenDash["per_page"] = 5;
    $configOpenDash["uri_segment"] = 4;

    $configPendingDash['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination">';        
    $configPendingDash['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';        
    $configPendingDash['first_link'] = 'First';        
    $configPendingDash['last_link'] = 'Last';        
    $configPendingDash['first_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item"><span class="page-link">';        
    $configPendingDash['first_tag_close'] = '</span></li>';        
    $configPendingDash['prev_link'] = '&laquo';        
    $configPendingDash['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item"><span class="page-link">';        
    $configPendingDash['prev_tag_close'] = '</span></li>';        
    $configPendingDash['next_link'] = '&raquo';        
    $configPendingDash['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item"><span class="page-link">';        
    $configPendingDash['next_tag_close'] = '</span></li>';        
    $configPendingDash['last_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item"><span class="page-link">';        
    $configPendingDash['last_tag_close'] = '</span></li>';        
    $configPendingDash['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" href="#">';        
    $configPendingDash['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';        
    $configPendingDash['num_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item"><span class="page-link">';        
    $configPendingDash['num_tag_close'] = '</span></li>';

    $configOpenDash['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination">';        
    $configOpenDash['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';        
    $configOpenDash['first_link'] = 'First';        
    $configOpenDash['last_link'] = 'Last';        
    $configOpenDash['first_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item"><span class="page-link">';        
    $configOpenDash['first_tag_close'] = '</span></li>';        
    $configOpenDash['prev_link'] = '&laquo';        
    $configOpenDash['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item"><span class="page-link">';        
    $configOpenDash['prev_tag_close'] = '</span></li>';        
    $configOpenDash['next_link'] = '&raquo';        
    $configOpenDash['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item"><span class="page-link">';        
    $configOpenDash['next_tag_close'] = '</span></li>';        
    $configOpenDash['last_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item"><span class="page-link">';        
    $configOpenDash['last_tag_close'] = '</span></li>';        
    $configOpenDash['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" href="#">';        
    $configOpenDash['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';        
    $configOpenDash['num_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item"><span class="page-link">';        
    $configOpenDash['num_tag_close'] = '</span></li>';

    $this->pagination->initialize($configPendingDash);
    $data["pendinglink"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    $this->pagination->initialize($configOpenDash);
    $data["openlink"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    $page2 = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;

    $data['pending_applications'] = $this->Users_model->get_count_pending_applications($configPendingDash["per_page"], $page);
    $data['open_applications'] = $this->Users_model->get_count_open_applications($configOpenDash["per_page"], $page2);
    
    $this->load->view('include/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('include/sidetopbar', $data);
    $this->load->view('user/dashboard', $data);
```

my model is:

```
public function get_count_open_applications()
{
    if(empty($searchBook))
    
    $this->db->where('col_status', 'OPEN');
    $this->db->from($this->tbl_loan_application);
    return $this->db->count_all_results();
}

public function get_count_pending_applications()
{
    $this->db->where('col_status', 'PENDING');
    $this->db->from($this->tbl_loan_application);
    return $this->db->count_all_results();
}

public function get_maximum_applications($limit, $start)
{
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from($this->tbl_loan_application);
    $this->db->where('col_status', 'PENDING');
    $this->db->order_by('loan_id','desc');
    $query=$this->db->get();
    return $query->result();

}

public function get_open_applications($limit, $start)
{
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from($this->tbl_loan_application);
    $this->db->where('col_status', 'OPEN');
    $this->db->order_by('loan_id','desc');
    $query=$this->db->get();

    return $query->result();
}
```

my view is:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-sm table-hover table-bordered">
                <thead class="thead">
                    <?php if(empty($pending_applications)){
                            echo "<strong>Whoops!</strong> Looks like there's no pending loans as of the moment.";
                        } else {?>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Company Code</th>
                        <th scope="col">Loan Type</th>
                        <th scope="col">Period</th>
                        <th scope="col">Borrower ID</th>
                        <th scope="col">Co-maker</th>
                        <th scope="col">Loanable</th>
                        <th scope="col">Terms</th>
                        <th scope="col">Status</th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                </thead>
                
                <tbody>
                    <?php foreach($pending_applications as $row): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">
                            <strong><?php echo $row->col_full_name; ?> </strong><br>
                            <?php echo $row->col_loan_assignid; ?>
                        </th>
                        <td><?php echo $row->col_comp_code; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->col_loan_type; ?></td>
                        <td scope="row">
                            <?php echo $row->col_dte_application; ?><br><br>
                            <?php echo $row->col_due_date; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->col_borrower_id; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->col_coMaker_perc; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->col_loanable; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->col_terms; ?></td>
                        <td>
                            <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-xs" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">Pending</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-link btn-xs">View</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <p><?php echo $pendinglink; ?></p>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Hey, Marleen. I edited my question to show my codes. Apologies.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

When creating the first set of pagination links, CodeIgniter divides the page offset value from the url by the `per_page` value from the configuration, and saves this internally as the current page value.

When you initialize the library for the second time, it does not seem to reset this current page value. And since it already has a current page value, it does not use the page offset from the url anymore, and marks the wrong page as "active" in the second set of pagination links.

You can solve this by setting `cur_page` manually for the second call to `initialize`:

Either set it to something that is considered "empty" by php to reset the page number and force CodeIgniter to use the value from the url again: `$configOpenDash['cur_page'] = 0;`

Or, if this gives problems with php8, set it explicitly like in your previous question:
`$configOpenDash['cur_page'] = $this->uri->segment(4) ?: -1;`

Comment: You saved us yet again, Marleen. Thank you so much!